# Laravel Auth::guard(guard)->check() not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am making a homework web app using Laravel and I am trying to add 3 different groups of people: admins, teachers and students. I have created all of these as models and they all have tables in the database. The login script works and logs the user in however the problem occurs when I use this code

```
    if(Auth::guard('student')->check() || Auth::guard('teacher')->check() || Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
        return Redirect::to('/admin/overview')->send();
    }
```

The login works because when I enter a correct username and password I get redirected away but when I use an incorrect username and password I get redirected to the same page.

My problem is that line of code doesn't do anything it seems that Auth::guard('student')->check() always returns false. Which is weird because this:

```
    if(Auth::guard('student')->attempt($credentials)) {
        return Redirect::to('/student/overview')->send();
    }
```

returns true and redirects me to /student/overview

Comment: Interested in this. Had this with different methods on the Guard functionality. Ended up debugging Laravel for hours and it seems the user isn't always passed around properly. Eventually just gave up on the guard and made `if (\Auth::user()->isAdmin() { ... }` checks. I would like to know what causes this to happen, because it even happens in clean install of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue then I tried first create the instance of `Auth` and then use `check()`

You need to manage this way just try this hope it helps you

```
$auth = Auth::guard('student');
if ($auth->check()) {
    return Redirect::to('/admin/overview')->send();
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, I don't know I am just really confused, my code is here https://github.com/JackPriceBurns/sinap/blob/authentication/app/Http/Controllers/LoginController.php

Comment: @user2710382 you have issue in your Admin and Teacher model just extend it by `Authenticatable`. `class Admin extends Authenticatable`

Comment: I didn't notice that! I have updated the files but I still don't know why Auth::guard('student')->check() is returning false :/

Comment: directly `Auth::guard('student')->check()` it won't work. You have to do the way i have specified. Just try that way

Comment: I just tried that and nothing... I might see if Laravel have a forums or IRC and ask there